# Downgrade to Java 8 from Java 10 on Mac so that Netbeans can work

Tags: macos, java, netbeans

I have java version 8, but when I type java -version in terminal I am getting java 10 version. I want my java version 8 back. 
In System Preferences, it is Showing Java 8 but when I see in terminal it is showing that I am using Java 10.0.2 version.

Netbeans is not working, i.e On clicking New Project no operation is performed.

Comment: Fix your path and any other Java related environment variables.

Comment: @DavidPostill Could you please suggest me the steps ?

Comment: Look at the install instructions for your version of Java

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using NetBeans 8.2, since that release will not work with any version of Java > 8.

If so, then you need to tell NetBeans to use Java 8 (and not Java 10) on startup. To do that:

- Close NetBeans 8.2 if it is running.
- Within your NetBeans 8.2 installation directory locate a directory named **etc**.
- Within that directory locate a configuration file named **netbeans.conf**.
- Open that file in any text editor. It is a simple text file containing property-value pairs.
- Locate the line containing the property `netbeans_jdkhome`. If that line is prefixed with a `#` symbol (to denote a comment) then remove that `#`.
- Replace whatever the value is for that property with the path to your JDK 8 installation. For example, on my Windows 10 machine that line looks like this for my NetBeans 8.2 installation: `netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_181"`
- Save your changes to `netbeans.conf` and start NetBeans. You should now be able to create a project in NetBeans 8.2 using JDK 8.

One final point: it doesn't matter what value is returned for `java -version` in a Terminal window. All that matters for NetBeans 8.2 to work is that it is configured to use Java 8.